# ERROR: there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "mail_message" Odoo Postgres

Tags: postgresql, odoo, odoo-14, postgresql-13

When I'm updating the base app I'm getting this error - **ERROR**: there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "mail_message".
for that i have execute this query too,
**Query** : `ALTER TABLE "mail_tracking_value" ADD FOREIGN KEY ("mail_message_id") REFERENCES "mail_message"("id") ON DELETE cascade;`

but I'm still facing the ERROR:  there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "mail_message"

In odoo14 the object mail.tracking.value has the foreign key which is mail_message_id of mail.the message,but it not granted this.

Comment: The error message  says, that there is no UNIQUE constraint on the mail_message ID. You can add it "alter table mail_message add constraint unique_id UNIQUE (id);" . If there are duplicates, you have to remove them first.
This issue can happen, for example, when restoring a broken DB dump after migration with duplicated IDs. Then, Odoo cannot create the unique constraint, thus, foreign keys don't work.